# Segfault in program that parses strings in a file and creates a binary tree

Tags: c, string, parsing, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

My program is receiving a segmentation fault when I run it. I run the gdb compiler to try and find out where it is, but it shows me this message, and I dont have a line 260 in my code haha, so I dont know what to do.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcmp_sse42 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp.S:260
260     movdqu  (%rsi), %xmm2
```

What my program does is reads in a text file and parses the strings, then it stores them into a binary tree. Then the user types in a command and I search the tree and see if the command is listed in the tree. I am going to post my full code so you all can see it, then post the file I read in and the sample output, and hopefully someone can help me with this segfault error. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#define COMMAND_NAME_LEN 50
#define MAX_SPLIT_SIZE 50
#define MAX_BUFF_SIZE 50

typedef struct Command_ {
    char name[COMMAND_NAME_LEN];
    int expected_param_count;
    struct Command_ *left;
    struct Command_ *right;
}Command;


typedef struct StringArray_ {
    char **strings;
    int size;
}StringArray;

StringArray* tokenizer (char *string, const char* delimiters);
void free_string_array(StringArray *sr);
void create_commands_tree(Command **commands, const char *file);
void insert_into_commands_tree(Command** node, char** data);
Command* get_command(Command *node, const char *command);
Command* create_command(char **data);
void destroy_commands_tree(Command* node);
void display_commands(Command *node);


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2) {
            printf("%s is missing commands.dat\n", argv[0]);
            return 0;
    }


    Command* options = NULL;
    create_commands_tree(&options,argv[1]);
    int checking = 1;

    char input_buffer[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];

    do {
            printf("Command: ");
            fgets(input_buffer,MAX_BUFF_SIZE,stdin);
            StringArray* parsed_input = tokenizer(input_buffer," \n");
            Command* c = get_command(options,parsed_input->strings[0]);

            if( c && parsed_input->size == c->expected_param_count) {
                    if (strcmp(c->name, "quit") == 0){
                                    checking = 0;
                    }
                    printf("Valid command used\n");
            }
            else {
                    printf("Invalid command, please try again\n");
            }
            free_string_array(parsed_input);

    }while (checking);

    destroy_commands_tree(options);

}


void create_commands_tree(Command **commands, const char *file) {

    FILE *input;
    input = fopen(file, "r");
    char strings[100];
    StringArray *temp2;

    while(fgets(strings,100,input)){

            temp2 = tokenizer(strings, "\n");
            insert_into_commands_tree(commands,temp2->strings);
    }
}

void insert_into_commands_tree(Command** node, char** data) {

    if(node == NULL){
            *node = create_command(data);
    }
    else if( node != NULL){
            if(strcmp(data[0],(*node)->name) < 0)
                    insert_into_commands_tree(&(*node)->left,data);
            else if(strcmp(data[0], (*node)->name) > 0)
                    insert_into_commands_tree(&(*node)->right,data);
    }


}

Command* create_command(char **data) {

    Command* new_;
    new_ = (Command*)malloc(sizeof(Command));
    strncpy(new_->name, data[0], COMMAND_NAME_LEN);
    new_->expected_param_count = atoi(data[1]);
    new_->right = NULL;
    new_->left = NULL;


    return new_;

}

Command* get_command(Command *node, const char *command) {

    Command *temp = node;
    int compare;

    if(temp){
            compare = strcmp(node->name, command);
            if(compare == 0){
                    return temp;
            }
            else if(compare < 0){
                    return (get_command(node->right, command));
            }
            else{
                    if(compare > 0){
                            return (get_command(node->left, command));
            }}

    }
   return temp;
}

void destroy_commands_tree(Command* node) {

    if( node == NULL){
            return;
            }

    destroy_commands_tree(node->left);
    destroy_commands_tree(node->right);
    free(node);

}
void display_commands(Command *node) {


            printf("\npickup <item>");
            printf("\nhelp ");
            printf("\nquit ");
            printf("\nload <file>\n\n");

}
 StringArray* tokenizer (char *string, const char* delimiters){

    StringArray* sr = malloc(sizeof(StringArray));
    sr->strings = malloc(MAX_SPLIT_SIZE * sizeof(char *));

    size_t len;
    char* hold;

    (sr->strings)[0] = malloc(MAX_BUFF_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    hold = strtok(string, delimiters);
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < MAX_SPLIT_SIZE; i++){

            hold = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
            if(hold == NULL){
                    sr->size = i + 1;
                    break;
            }
            (sr->strings)[i] = malloc(MAX_BUFF_SIZE * sizeof(char));
            strcpy((sr->strings)[i], hold);
    }
    return sr;
}

void free_string_array(StringArray *sr) {

     int i;
    for(i = 0; i < sr->size; ++i){
             free(sr->strings[i]);
    }
            free(sr->strings);
            free(sr);
}
```

Here is the sample output that was given:

```
]$ ./a.out commands.dat 
Command: pickup 
Invalid command, please try again 
Command: pickup ball 
Valid command used 
Command: quit 1 
Invalid command, please try again 
Command: load 
Invalid command, please try again 
Command: load bak.sav 
Valid command used 
Command: help
Valid command used
Command: help 2 
Invalid command, please try again 
Command: quit 
Valid command used
```

And the file that we read in is as follows:

```
pickup,2
help,1
quit,1
load,2
```

Comment: The segfault is line 260 in the system library that supplies strcmp. Look at your use of strcmp and make sure you only ever pass it a valid buffer (and use strncmp anyway, it's safer). If you were to run it in a debugger you could navigate up the stack and find where your code calls into the system code and determine your problem.

Comment: Do you think it has to do with my insert function then?

Comment: All you can say from your segfault is that it relates to strcmp. As I said, build it with debugging symbols, run it in gdb, wait for it to crash, type "where". And it'll show you the entire call graph. It's also worth noting that strncpy can strip off the required NUL from the end of a string if it's the exact size of the buffer.

Comment: Also, please see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266270/specific-warnings-to-newbies-about-homework-code-writing-please-debug-and-sscce?cb=1

Comment: @joe thanks I didnt know I could type where in gdb that helps a lot. Its on line 116

Answer (score 1):

`tokenizer` allocates and returns a pointer to a `StringArray`, but you never free it.  You should free each one in `create_commands_tree`.

`tokenizer`throws away the first result from `strtok` which probably isn't what you want.  You're allocating `sr->strings[0]` but never copying anything into it.

`create_command` and `insert_into_commands_tree` should be passed a `StringArray`, not a `char **`.  You're allocating and initializing this struct, you might as well use it.  Otherwise these functions will have no idea how many tokens are being passed into them.